# Типизация объекта в котором нужно ключи сделать значениями

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Есть такое задание:

> Implement the *invert* function which inverts the given object.
>
> For example:

```
invert({ 1: "a", 2: "b" }); // {a: 1, b: 2}
```

Вот такие тесты

```
describe('object invert', () => {
    it('should return {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} for given input {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c"}', () => {
        assert.deepStrictEqual(invert({1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c"}), {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3});
    });
    it('should return {one: "first", two: "second"} for given input {first: "one", second: "two"}', () => {
        assert.deepStrictEqual(invert({"first": 'one', "second": 'two'}), {"one": 'first', "two": 'second'});
    });

    it('should return {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c"} for given input {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}', () => {
        assert.deepStrictEqual(invert({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}), {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c"});
    });
});
```

Написал такую функцию:

```
export default function invert<T, K extends T[keyof T]>(obj: T): K {
    const result = {}
    for(const key in obj) {
        result[obj[key]] = isNaN(Number(key)) ? key : +key
    }
    return result
}
```

Но typescript ругается, как все таки можно типизировать эту функцию?

Comment: *>typescript ругается* - на чё ругается то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка, которую вы видите связана с тем что TypeScript не может использовать значение `obj[key]` для индексации объекта типа `K`, так как TypeScript не может гарантировать, что `obj[key]` является допустимым ключом для типа `K`, и из-за этого возникает ошибка. Чтобы избежать этого нужно немного поменять код и типы:

Первым делом нужно добавить ограничение для параметра `T` чтобы убедиться, что он расширяет `Record<string, any>`, чем мы назначаем что `T` должен быть объектом с ключами строкового типа.

Затем ввести новую переменную `value`, чтобы сохранить значение из `obj[key]`, и использовать эту переменную при присвоении значений `result`.

```typescript
export default function invert<T extends Record<string, any>, K extends T[keyof T]>(obj: T): Record<K, keyof T> {
  const result: Record<K, keyof T> = {} as Record<K, keyof T>
  for (const key in obj) {
    const value = obj[key] as K
    result[value] = key as keyof T
  }
  return result
}
```